# Solve $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[w^3\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(w)]$

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

$$\frac{\pi}{64\mu}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ w^3\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{E}{2H}w \right) \right] = \frac{1}{4}\frac{\pi E}{128\mu H}\frac{\partial^2w^4}{\partial x^2}$$
with $w(x,t)$

Is this correct?
And if so, why?

Specifically this part:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[w^3\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(w)\right]$$

The entire formula is that of the PKN-model for hydraulic fracturing, but I'm stuck on this part. Specifically formula 49 and 50 of [fracoptima](http://www.frackoptima.com/userguide/theory/governing-equations-kgdpkn.html#pkn-equation).

Comment: "Solve" is the wrong word here. One solves problems; one solves equations; one _evaluates_ expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\frac{\partial ^2 \omega^4}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\omega^4 \right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(4 \omega^3\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x} \right)=4\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( \omega^3\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x} \right)
$$

Comment: It's late... thank you